# External JavaScript not linking to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Really sorry the stupid question. I've seen the WordPress Codex, and I think I'm adhering to the standards. I'm trying to get **tran.js** to load, but it simply won't. Here is my entire functions.php:

```
<?php

function PA_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'PA-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PA_stylesheet' );

function PA_javascript() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/tran.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PA_javascript' );

?>
```

Would anyone be able to help me out?

Comment: Did you get some 404 errors on your console|firebug|etc. ?

Comment: Ah, for some reason it's calling `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function` on `$(document).ready(function () {` ?

Comment: It means that your file is correctly included.
Try:
`$.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });`

Comment: Thanks. I've included the plugin `http://jquerydevbrazil.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.center.js` but is calling `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'center' ` ?

Comment: It is likely that your script make the call to `center` method before `jquery.center.js` being included

Comment: I've put the `center` script after the `jquery` script in my `functions.php`.  Should that not solve it?

Comment: Please check the order of your `<script>...</script>` includes within `<head>...</head>` meta tag and near closing body tag

Comment: I think I'm just calling them from `<?php wp_head(); ?>` ?

Comment: Do you have a link to show us?

Comment: Yes — http://herbert-theme.info/

Comment: I get no error, i can see all your included files

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including this in your header?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/trans.js"></script>
```

If that doesn't work, you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/trans.js"></script>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: Nope, still nothing. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your function PA_javascript, make sure you enqueue the jquery script. Not all themes will automatically enqueue it.

After that, make sure you are setting the right path to your custom JS file. Use a debugging tool such as Firebug for Firefox and watch the NET tab to look for 404 errors or console errors.